# Google Adsense for rss feeds with parameters (user-created feeds)

Tags: rss, adsense, atom-feed, feedburner

I have a website where users can select some options and based on the selected values an atom feed will be generated.
Now I would like to add ads to the feed using Google Adsense, which points me to Feedburner.
But Feedburner seems to support only static urls.
Unless of course I manually create a Feedburner feed for every combination a user can enter, but that's not feasible..

[Related question I found](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/parameters-in-feedburner-feeds)

Comment: Good question. I would also like to know if there are any workarounds for this.

Comment: AdSense for feeds are no longer an option https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2777193